# Why is this Flask-SQLAlchemy code block executing twice?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Code sample of app.py:

```
# imports here

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('app.cfg')
db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    if os.path.exists('database/example.db'):
        print 'already exists'
    else:
        print 'database created'
        db.create_all()


#routes here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

On the initial load it will print 'database created' and then 'already exists'. If I load it again when the database has been created, 'already exists' prints twice.

```
already exists
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
already exists
```

Two part question:

1) Why is with app.app_context() block executing twice?

2) What is the better way to write this code?

Comment: As the output says, it's the automatic code reloader that restarts your code. It's supposed to do this whenever your code changes while the app is running, it's only enabled in debug mode (maybe you should show your `app.cfg`). However, in the case the database is already there, I really do not see what is changing, so no clue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what happens go back to python basics. When you type `python your_module.py` python interpreter will read (interpreter) your code line by line. In this case it will execute your `with app.app_context` code when it arrives there and you will see the output *database create* first time or *already exists* next times. What happens next? Interpreter will simply continue to your `if __name__ == '__main__':` line and then since you run it directly it will call `app.run` method and by default the `debug` parameter is `True` and it will start the development server in debug mode and the automatic reloader will restarts your code (as mentioned by @burnpanck).